# Injectable singleton service yet not new()able .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, singleton

Using .net-core DI framework, I'm registering my Foo service as singleton:

```
 services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();
```

Yet, I don't want any other developer to create new instance of Foo service:

```
var storage = new TokenStorage();  // bad practice, not allowed
```

I know I can make Foo service internally singleton with non-accessible constructor like below:

```
public class Foo : IFoo 
{
   private static _instance;
   
   protected Foo() {}
   
   public static IFoo GetInstance()
   { 
      return _instance ??= new Foo();
   }
}
```

But I don't want traditional way of accessing this service using ***Foo.GetInstance().Bar()***

In simple words, I want DI framework to make Foo singleton and yet abandon developers from instantiating it by new Foo(), without using Singleton pattern.

Is there any way or pattern to achieve this?

Comment: I can't understand, you've already said to the DI machanism, that your registered class is a singleton, mechanism will now take care about it, each time users will inject the IFoo, they will get the same instance, created during the first request.

Comment: @IvanKhorin: The OP is basically trying to prevent `new` from being used directly.  It can't be done, AFAIK.  You need accessibility to a type to use the type, but any attempt to scuttle the constructors or factory methods of a type would tightly bind the DI framework to the type, which sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes. DI should just care about injection, but I want a non-newable type, no matter someone uses DI or not. I myself think it's not possible, but worries me a lot, specially when driving a hardware. I always use GetInstance() though

Comment: why don't you simply inject the singleton? like `services.AddSingleton<IFoo>(() => Foo.GetInstance());`?

Comment: @MarkusDresch You hit the nail on the head

Comment: (This isn't the point of your question, but your singleton isn't thread-safe)

Comment: @canton7 Thanks. Implementation is for brevity. There are many other things to consider too:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/singleton-design-pattern-in-C-Sharp/#:~:text=Thread%20Safety%20Singleton&text=This%20implementation%20is%20thread%2Dsafe,thread%20will%20create%20an%20instance.

Comment: Cool, just making sure you're aware!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `Foo` using singleton pattern, then [provide a factory function that retrieves the singleton instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Type_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider_System_Object__) when registering `IFoo`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>(_ => Foo.GetInstance());
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the implementation of `Foo` to the project that contains your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). As that project already depends on all other projects in the application, it will be impossible (without manually hacking the project files) to let those projects refer back the startup project (as that would cause a cyclic dependency). This effectively hides `Foo` from all other projects. Those projects can only depend on the `IFoo` abstraction and they can never accidentally create a new instance of `Foo`.

In case `Foo` contains too much logic to move, alternatively, you can make `Foo` abstract and create a `FooImpl` derivative inside the Composition Root and register that. The effect is the same; code inside other projects can't create `FooImpl` because they don't have a reference to the startup project.

This method prevents you from having to use the Singleton Design Pattern, which problematic in the case `Foo` is a [Volatile Dependency](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/section-1-3-2) (which it likely is as you hid it behind an abstraction).

Answer (score -1):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    interface IFoo { int FooProp { get; } }

    interface IBar { int BarProp { get; } }

    class Foo : IFoo { public int FooProp => 10; }

    class Bar : IBar { public int BarProp => 10; }

    class Program
    {
        static readonly ServiceProvider _serviceProvider = ConfigureServices().BuildServiceProvider();

        static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices() =>
            new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>()
                .AddTransient<IBar, Bar>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureServices();

            var foo1 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFoo>();
            var foo2 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFoo>();

            var bar1 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBar>();
            var bar2 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBar>();

            Console.WriteLine($"foo1 & foo2 are {(foo1 == foo2 ? "same" : "different")} instances.");
            Console.WriteLine($"bar1 & bar2 are {(bar1 == bar2 ? "same" : "different")} instances.");
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
foo1 & foo2 are same instances.
bar1 & bar2 are different instances.

Comment: What if someone doesn't know about injection and resolving a required service ? Foo should not be instantiated in project scope, and no one should be able to do that manually using new Foo()

Comment: @Efe Then they probably shouldn't be modifying your code base :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen repo forkers are always there, just like customers that wrestle with app :)

Comment: @Efe, why you care about someone's forks? Is it your headache? It's their choice to shoot the leg :)

Comment: @IvanKhorin Then your Ubuntu might format your hard drive in background :D

Comment: @Elf, I try to avoid beta testing of unknown software :)

Comment: @IvanKhorin When you define a restriction, it should be a restriction. Rule is sth else.